# JSP EL + jQuery "$.ajax()" problem

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, el

I have simple JSP:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="severity" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>
<jsp:directive.attribute name="currentSeverity" type="java.lang.String" required="true"/>

<c:if test="${severity ne currentSeverity}">
    <c:url value="/session" var="url">
        <c:param name="severity" value="${severity}"/>
    </c:url>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '${url}',
        success: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });"><c:out value="${severity}"/></a></li>
</c:if>
```

But when I'm evaluate it servlet engine throws:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
  /WEB-INF/tags/severity-position.tagx(17,9) PWC6287: 
  The attribute prefix success does not correspond to any imported tag library
```

Somehow JSP engine thinks that `$.ajax({...});` string is JSP EL expression (no matter what characters are placed between `$` and `{`). When I backslash `{` or `$` it's all ok, but then my IDE thinks that this code is broken JS code.

So, why JSP engine thinks that `$.ajax({...})` is JSP EL expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look indeed like a bug in the EL implementation used by the servletcontainer (or webapplication) in question. You need to figure which one it is using and try upgrading/replacing it.

If upgrading/replacing the EL implementation doesn't help, then I'd warmly recommend do move that whole script out into an function in its own `.js` file which you load using `<script>` in the HTML `<head>` element. That's also the normal practice. Even more, I'd give the link a classname so that you can just hook on it during `$(document).ready()` and add the `click()` accordingly. E.g.

```
<a href="${url}" class="someName">
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.someName').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('href'), // This sets the actual value of ${url}.
            success: function() {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false; // Blocks link from executing the default href action.
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm using Jetty for developing. I tried tomcat and glassfish JSP engine implementations. It seems that both of them are have this issue.

I think that separation of concerns is good idea anyway, so I moved JS code away from JSP template. Thanks a lot.